# Mailchimp Campaign Archive not showing all content from campaign folder

Tags: jquery, mailchimp

Okay so I finally figured out how to add the campaign archive to the site. The issue I have is that the archive is only displaying 3 of my items from the campaign folder. I went to lists --> sign up forms --> General Forms then I selected the dropdown for campaign archive and selected the correct folder with 23 items in it. I would like to display at least 20 of these items but I cannot find a way to display more than 3. Any help is much appreciated. Ive spent the better part of today trying to figure this out and there doesn't seem to be a viable solution anywhere....

Thanks

Comment: any update on this mate?